# how to convert a .csv file to .bag in python?

Tags: python, csv, ros, lidar, rosbag

I have some VLP16 LiDar data in .csv file format, have to load the data in Ros Rviz for which I need the Rosbag file(.bag). I have tried finding it in the Ros tutorial, what I got was to convert .bag to .csv

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually expert in processing .bag files but I think you need to go through your CSV file and manually add the values using rosbag [Python API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API)

Answer (score -1):

Not direct answer but check this [script](https://gist.github.com/mintar/d6c0dbd3e9e5dd1b1af0441689607ed7) in python, which might help you.

Regarding C++ I propose this repository: [convert_csv_to_rosbag](https://github.com/zhousunchun/convert_csv_to_rosbag) which is even closer to what you asked.

However, it seems that you need to do it by yourself based on these examples.